# Chromium, Ubuntu Software won't start

Tags: software-center, chromium

I am unable to have Chromium or the Ubuntu Software start up when I try to launch them. I have tried removing/purging both and reinstalling without any luck.

The programs worked fine a day before and the last thing I changed was installing wine. I have also completely removed wine, winetricks and play on linux to solve the issue but nothing has worked so far.

Using the terminal for launching chromium via `chromium-browser` gives the following output:

```
/snap/chromium/1229/bin/desktop-launch: line 321: [: too many arguments
/snap/chromium/1229/bin/desktop-launch: line 321: [: too many arguments
/snap/chromium/1229/bin/desktop-launch: line 321: [: too many arguments
Gtk-Message: 16:25:46.312: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 16:25:46.313: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I have tried rectifying the above using `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module` but it just confirms that I have the latest module so changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have something to do with fonts. Uninstall any new fonts and that should fix it.

Here's the link I came across that helped me solve this: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/chromium-file-chooser-is-not-displaying-font/17021/4